# Cecilia users ?

Tags: software

Hi

Would any Cecilia users out there be willing to give a short overview of its features; strengths/weaknesses etc?

Also how does one go about installing it - I guess I need to install CSound first but which version is compatible with the current Cecilia build?

Thanks

rich

Answer (score 1):

The actual version of Cecilia 5 has been recoded in python with the pyo library. It can be found there: https://code.google.com/p/cecilia5/

You don't really need any coding skill to get it working properly, it is user friendly.

I use it on occasion for synthesis SFX, the biggest strength, in my opinion, is that you can set automation in time on a lot of parameter of the synthesis/sounds effects attribute. So it can create some pretty unique weird sounds. 
And 
It is free...

Answer (score 0):

A considerable time sink. Probably the closest you can get to "(non-real-time) Kyma on a personal computer" (another would be [The Composer's Desktop Project](http://www.composersdesktop.com/)).

Useful for study purposes in sound synthesis as well as many audio DSP implementations and by having the CSound backend can do really fine and high-quality sounds and sample processing although with the cumbersome manual/non-real-time operation.

Generally not worth the time investment (depends on how you personally perceive Cecilia's or CSound's "usefulness" though), but if you're determined to use it, well, technically it packs a punch (especially if you look carefully through what CSound is really easy to use for [things involving loads of oscillators, filters and modulation for example] or what audio DSP effects are quite unique to CSound e.g. http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/pvcross.html, http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/pvsvoc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Cecilia in a long time but I am an avid Csound user. If I remember correctly, the latest 4.2 beta comes with csound prepackaged, so theoretically you only need to download cecilia itself:

[Cecilia Download Page](https://code.google.com/p/cecilia4/downloads/list)

As Internet Human already mentioned, learning csound (which you will need to do in order to use Cecilia successfully) takes time and the learning curve can be quite steep at first. However, I do believe that it's well worth it, and contrary to Internet Human's claim you can actually use Csound in realtime.

Comment:   Yeah well, the "real-timeness" seems to be slightly subjective. Yes, you can play CSound instruments in real-time (after some boilerplate commands and setting it up), and yes, you can modify parameters in real-time. It's just a lot different (more cumbersome and very oldschool) compared to how DAWs and VSTs work. Or even something like Max or PD, which are real-time by design. More info: http://www.csounds.com/journal/issue13/emulatingMidiBasedStudios.html (from 2010). 